# Troubleshooting docker intermitted failure issue for cgroup process

Tags: docker

Let me try to describe my situation here (trying best to capture whatever information I have).

We have a production level service which consists of many dockers containing multiple services running in cloud (asuzre) VM.

Now if we keep on running it for long (long >= 5 days) as a part of Longivity testing, we can see -- sometimes (i.e. not always after 5 days, sometimes) - services start failing, denial of services to our clients.

```
ERROR: for health-checker  Cannot start service health-checker: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:297: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"failed to write 1 to memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes: write /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/ad4926b8e5b583ce3ae30d4e3d1f1379ee89fc2735d83a87b127ef4e1e7089db/memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes: cannot allocate memory\"": unknown {}

ERROR: for credentials  Cannot start service credentials: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:297: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"failed to write 1 to memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes: write /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/5b2cef0997776af7265fcc41bd640059a29fc723375e43acde63514f58ec6055/memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes: cannot allocate memory\"": unknown {}

ERROR: for occm  Cannot start service occm: runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:297: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"failed to write 1 to memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes: write /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/9d5912c7459a514c6f9bdaa3a170b1bf0ba4fa3189b482b72c2013a85cf5b8ba/memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes: cannot allocate memory\"": unknown {}

failed to perform container upgrade task. java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to deploy containers {akkaAddress=akka://some-manager, akkaSource=akka://some-manager/user/service-deployer, sourceActorSystem=some-manager}
```

So as a consequence, none of our services are accessible, all the https calls are denied:

```
Name does not resolve {}\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-07-02T03:38:29.720361925Z"}

Name does not resolve {}\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-07-02T03:38:29.744298675Z"}
```

I was trying doing lots of google and try to get something actionable and meaningful from where to start.

Any pointer / insight / clue will be highly appreciated.

(I understand I may not be very detailed or very pin pointing the issue - actually I am bit clueless as it's failing sometimes after 5 days of run.)

Seeking guidance.
Pradip

Comment: If anyone can please provide some clue, would be of great help.

Comment: did you get any solution for it?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: These kernel parameters fixed the issue for me: https://doc.arvados.org/main/install/install-docker.html

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your docker & containerd after upgrading the kernel.

This happened to me after upgrading 5.4.6 -> 5.18.5 in one go. Rebuilding docker & containerd packages solved it.